# Creating new core classes (not replacing)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm looking for a method to create other core classes. There is no purpose of my code extending the current core and no use in creating it as a controller.

Is there somewhere that is specified what is to be auto-loaded?
I started with a very basic file

Application/core/world.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class CI_Worlds{

    function __construct(){
        die('this is the end of the world');
    }
}

?>
```

Trying to access it with `$this->load->library('Worlds');`
Have also tried other alternatives for the class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All auto loaded files are specified in `config/autoload.php`. If you want to create a totally new class, place it inside the libraries directory.

If you want to auto load it, open `config/autoload.php` and include the class name under $autoload['libraries']:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('CI_Worlds');
```

Comment: Exactly right. New classes, outside of the CI framework, go in libraries. Hacking core just makes upgrades harder and you lose all the features built around handling libraries (like autoload).

Answer (score 0):

Autoloading classes via `$autoload[...]` has a little disadvantage: an object of the class is automatically instantiated and becomes accessible with `->class_name` from CI ,,superobject'' (please look at `Loader::_ci_autoloader()` in `system/core/Loader.php`). Being accessible is just not elegant, but instantiating can be unwanted or needless.

This is my solution:

File `MY_Loader.php` in `application/core`

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
{
  const MY_AUTOLOADER_CONFIG = 'my_autoloader';

  /******************************************************************************************/

  private $search_paths = array();

  /******************************************************************************************/

  private function register_autoloader(array $search_paths)
  {
    foreach($search_paths as $path)
      if ($path = realpath($path))
        $this->search_paths[] = $path;

    if (empty($this->search_paths))
      throw new LogicException('Autoloader search_paths does not contain any valid path');
    else
      spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'autoloader'));
  }

  /**
    * Based on idea from http://www.highermedia.com/articles/nuts_bolts/codeigniter_base_classes_revisited
    */
  private function autoloader($class_name)
  {
    if (!class_exists($class_name, false)) // false == no autoload ;)
      foreach($this->search_paths as $path)
      {
        $file_name = $path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$class_name.'.php';
        if (file_exists($file_name))
          include_once($file_name);
      }      
  }

  /******************************************************************************************/

  /**
    * extension of CI_Loader::_ci_autoloader()
    */
  protected function _ci_autoloader()
  {
    $config = load_class('config', 'core');
    if ($config->load(self::MY_AUTOLOADER_CONFIG, TRUE, TRUE))
      $this->register_autoloader(
        $config->item('search_paths', self::MY_AUTOLOADER_CONFIG)
      );

    parent::_ci_autoloader();
  }

}
```

And an example of `config/my_autoloader.php`

```
<?php

$config['search_paths'] = array(
  APPPATH.'core'
);
```

Classes included with this code are NOT automatically instantiated.

Also it's worth to remember about some drawbacks: CI may fail if a class loaded with this code is also loaded somewhere with CI's code. Or in other words: one has to keep files and classes not to interfere with each other.